# error 503 en solicitudes desde un servidor nodejs a la Api de milChimp

Tags: nodejs, curl, http-post

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web y necesito mediante la API de mailChimp agregar contactos a una audiencia pero me retorna el error 503. En mi país su pagina web esta restringida y me conecto mediante VPN y creo que es por eso. Hay alguna forma de realizar solicitudes http desde un servidor node.js a otro mediante un VPN o un proxy. Este es el error que me retorna

```
{
"type": "akamai_error_message",
"title": "akamai_503",
"status": 503,
"ref_no": "Reference Number: 00.2fa42b17.1683406120.33a27a2"
```

}